# JavaScript: convert an array of arrays which contain strings into an array of arrays which contain objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I know it's a simple questions... But I got stacked. I want to convert an arrays of arrays which contain strings into an array of arrays which contain objects.

```
what_i_have = [
  [
    "{"point1":"recommendation number 1 text"}",
    "{"point2":"recommendation number 2 text"}"
  ],
  [
    "{"point1":1.5}","{"ponit2":2}"
  ],
  [
    "{"point1":1.5}","{"point2":2}"
  ]
]
```

I want to get this:

```
what_i_want = [
  [
    {"point1":"recommendation number 1 text"}, 
    {"point2":"recommendation number 2 text"}
  ],
  [
    {"point1":1.5},{"ponit2":2}
  ],
  [
    {"point1":1.5},{"point2":2}
  ]
]
```

I tried several ways. The last way with JSON.parse() elements of arrays. But there is something I did wrong all times. 
Any suggestion will be truly welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well your first code is not valid.

Comment: Can you check your single and double quotes?

Comment: One of the problems is that all the "theoretically" strings I have use double quotes for everything. So it causes a problem for parsing, I think. Any suggestion to tackle this extra problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is what you want, i.e.

```
what_i_want  = what_i_have.map(arr => arr.map(str => JSON.parse(str)))
```

There are some problems with `"` in your code example, but ignoring that `map` should do what you want.

Comment: True. I receive the initial array as you can see in my questions. It causes a problem for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` and `map` like this:

```
var result = what_i_have.map(function(subarr) {
    return subarr.map(function(str) {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over with JSON.parse

```js
what_i_have = [
  [
    '{"point1":"recommendation number 1 text"}', '{"point2":"recommendation number 2 text"}'
  ],
  [
    '{"point1":1.5}', '{"ponit2":2}'
  ],
  [
    '{"point1":1.5}', '{"point2":2}'
  ]
]
for (var i = 0; i < what_i_have.length; i++) {
  var arr = what_i_have[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    arr[j] = JSON.parse(arr[j]);
  }
}
console.log(what_i_have);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, one of the problems is that all the "theoretically" strings I have use double quotes for everything. So it causes a problem for parsing, I think. Any suggestion to tackle this extra problem?

Comment: Um, it is impossible to do that because the JavaScript would not execute, it would throw an error. Did you try to run the code and see if it runs?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Than you either do not have valid JSON or the string issue is at fault.

Comment: That is what I receive as data. I know that's not proper JSON. Maybe creating a condition to replace that initial double quotation marks.

Comment: The problem is the fact that the inner quotes makes it a bug. This: `var a = "foo"bar"world";` is a bug. The inner quotes would need to be escaped for it to be valid. `var a = "foo\"bar\"world";` If you need to fix the serverside code, would make sense to not have it wrapped it in the first place and just have the objects.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello for your explanations. You've helped me to identify the issue. Now I know that my parse attempts weren't the problem.